# Android Compatibility Library on Honeycomb

Tags: android

Could anyone clarify one moment about ACL - if my app was build with ACL and runs on Honeycomb device is it still use ACL classes or Honeycomb platform native? 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are linking the ACL classes, then it uses ACL